Suppressing TextBox based on Data FIelds (Crystal Reports 2013)
I have a text box named  Cust No:
and a string named
CAR_ITEM.ARCUSTO_CUSTNO
When CAR_ITEM.ARCUSTO_CUSTNO has a value of null I want it to also to NOT display the text field named   Cust No:
I know how to suppress a string field but I'm not sure how to tie it to it's associated text field?
I have multiple Text/strings in one Details section. So I will have to do this with each one.

Thanks!
I tried if isnull({fieldname}) then TRUE. But don't know how to add the code to tie this in with the text of Cust No:

Right-click the text object,
Select Format Text...
In the Common tab, click the button to enter an expression for the Suppress property:


Thanks. I try that and can suppress the string but not the text box Cust No: associated with the string.   That doesn't do me any good in the end because I could accomplish the same thing but not suppressing anything at all.  If the value is null then that text box Cust No: will just have a blank space next to it which is what i want but I also don't want Cust No: to show up on the report either.

Ok I figured it out. It was quite easy.  Just had to highlight both the text and string, right click, suppress and write the expression if isnull({fieldname}) then TRUE  :) thank you for your help!  :)
